# All shortest paths between 2 nodes in undirected, unweighted graph in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, graph, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

I need some help implementing a shortest path problem in Mysql and Php. From what I know, the BFS algorithm is the best way to find these paths in undirected and unweighted graphs. Still, I have to get all the shortest paths from a vertex to another and this gets more complicated. I have found a Java implementation for this, but is far too complicated for me to transcribe it into Sql.

So, first question would be: where should I do the computations? Mysql or Php? Where would it be faster?

Also, is BFS the best option for this? Is there any easier to implement solution? If not, does anybody have a easy to follow and adapt code with I could use as a reference?

Thanks!

Comment: Graph traversals in MySQL are painful, because there is no support for hierarchical data structures, recursive CTEs, or other graph structures.  Other databases *do* have such functionality, but not MySQL.  You would have to use recursive or looping constructs in stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Storing complex hierarchical data in a flat relational database like MySQL is not trivial, let alone searching it algorithmically. I certainly wouldn't recommend trying to implement the algorithm for searching a graph in SQL at all.

As far as implementing Breadth First Search in PHP there are some good [Tree implementations in PHP](https://github.com/morrisonlevi/Ardent) out there on github that might help. [A good article for reference on dealing with btrees in PHP](http://phpden.info/binary-search-trees-in-php) - *specific to PHP*. Not specific enough to weighted, undirected graphs, but general enough that it might offer a bit of direction. Breadth First search is basically just a queue/stack where you pop leaf nodes off the branches so it's not hard to implement iteratively or recursively.

The easiest way to do shortest path search, in my opinion, is [A* search](http://phpden.info/A*-path-finding-algorithm), even though it is not guaranteed to find **all** shortest paths, like BFS, since it typically stops as soon as it's found the end node, it can be much easier to implement and not impossible to tweak to search all paths.

There's also Dijkstra's algorithm, which that and A* are both pretty popular for finding shortest path. Here's a good [cs.stackexchange answer I found on contrast between Dijktra and BFS for shortest path](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18138/dijktra-algorithm-vs-breath-first-search-for-shortest-path-in-graph).

Hope that helps.